# Filter on a BindingSource : did the DataSource must be a DataTable

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, datatable

I have a `DataGridView` that I bind on a `BindingSource`.

The thing is, when I do a filter on it, it doesn't work.

Is it needed, to add `Filter` on a BndingSource `DataSource`, that the `DataSource` is a `DataTable`.

For now, it is jst a list of Object, but I can return a `DataTable`.

Should I change it or not?

```
bindingSource1.DataSource = Echange.GetListEchange(contextExecution.ChaineConnexion, criteres);
```

GetListEchange, return a list of Echange.

But with this, the filter doesn't work :

```
        bindingSource1.Filter =  "ec.date_echange IS NULL";
```

So, this will work if I return a `DataTable` instead?
Hope I can use `Filter` without returning a `DataTable` but, if I have to do it, no problem.

Generate the DataTable :

```
        vRequete += vFrom + " " + vWhere.Trim().TrimEnd("AND".ToCharArray()) + " " + vOrderBy;

        vTable = vTarget.RenvoiOneTable(vRequete);
```

RenvoieOneTable is a method providing by Oracle. The code is :

```
public override DataTable RenvoiOneTable(string piRequest)
        {
            DataTable poDatable = null;

            try
            {
                poDatable = ChargeDataSet(piRequest).Tables[0];
            }
            catch (OracleException ThisException)
            {
                throw new BaseDonneesException(ThisException.Message);
            }
            catch (Exception ThisExcept)
            {
                throw new BaseDonneesException(ThisExcept.Message);
            }

            return poDatable;
        }

     public override DataSet ChargeDataSet(string piRequest)
            {
                DataSet poDataset = null;

                try
                {
                    //Ouverture de la connection
                    Connexion.Open();

                    //Initialisation de la commande
                    Command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

                    //Mise en place dans la variable po_datasets de l'identifiant et du
                    //dataset voulu
                    Command.CommandText = piRequest;

                    using (OracleDataAdapter vAdapter = new OracleDataAdapter(Command))
                    {
                        poDataset = new DataSet();
                        vAdapter.Fill(poDataset);
                    }

                }
                catch (OracleException ThisException)
                {
                    throw new BaseDonneesException(ThisException.Message);
                }
                catch (Exception ThisExcept)
                {
                    throw new BaseDonneesException(ThisExcept.Message);
                }
                finally
                {
                    if (Connexion.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                    {
                        Connexion.Close();
                    }

                }
                //Envoye du tableau de DataSet
                return poDataset;
            }
```

Thank you.

Comment: You have a column named `ec.date_echange`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `DataGridView` can only deal with one set of 2D information (i.e., one `DataTable`). Although it is not bad to rely on a `Binding` variable (actually, it is recommended by [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.datasource%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)), the reality is that the DataGridView only relates to one of its DataTables (in case of having more than one in the binding source, you would have to specify the one you want to be the `DataSource` via the `DataMember` property).

Thus, any change you want to do in the DataSource has to be done in the given DataTable, in case of considering a binding source; and thus the behaviour you are observing is the expected one.

Comment: Then, all DataPropertyName of my columns must have a name in the dataTable? I must concat(if I want to) in my dataTable, and not anywhere else? Oh, wierd problem : why is my dataGrid displaying 5 rows, while my  dataTable only got 4 rows?

Comment: @Zaphod 5 rows when your DataTable has just 4? Is the last one blank I presume? If you are getting in your DataGridView any (not-blank) information not present in the given DataTable, this would certainly be weird (unless, logically, you are adding this information "manually" to the DataGridView). Could you please elaborate a bit more on all this? Ideally, you should post your code where you are populating the DataTable, feeding it to the Binding variable and setting this as the DataSource of the DataGridView.

Comment: @Zaphod Your code is fine. I guess that you mean the last blank row which is included when `AllowUserToAddRows` is set to true (this is where the user is expected to add more values); if you set this flag to false this additional row would disappear. Also bear in mind that, precisely to avoid this kind of problems (this row is accounted by `Rows.Count`, but its contents are null), while iterating through DGV cells, you should always set a heading condition checking whether the given cell is null before trying to edit it.

Comment: @varocabas Yes, it was the `AllowUserToAddRows ` Thank you. I don't understant the meaning in the end of your comment. Don't worry, it is just a dataGrid to see data on a dataBase, and print some of infos.

Comment: (my nick is varocarbas) What I said is that the Rows.Count property might be seen as not as "reliable" as in other collections. For example: List<string> list = new List<string>(); list.Add("1"); list.Add("2"); list.Count = 2 and thus you can be sure that any element between 0 and Count - 1 is not null. But DGV might include an additional null row (because of the aforementioned AllowUserToAddRows, for example) and thus if you iterate through its elements and don't check for nulls (what you don't need to do with list), an error might be provoked. I hope that everything is clear now.

Comment: I guess that your question has been answered, isn't it? (this last additional-row bit wasn't even part of your original question).